# can't find if palindrome or not from this

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int i,l,count=0;
    char str[100];
    printf("Enter a string\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", str);
    l=strlen(str);
    printf("%d\n", l);
    for(i=0;i<=l/2;i++)
    {
        if(str[i]==str[l-i])
            count++;
        else
            continue;
    }
    printf("%d", count);

    if(count==l/2)
        printf("the string is pallindrome");
    else
        printf("\nNOt pallindrome");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the string is “abccba”, what is the length of the string? What is character 0 of the string? What is character 6 of the string? What is character 5 of the string? Which character should character 0 be compared to?

Comment: I think you have an off-by-one error when examining the end of the string. For the first iteration of the `for` loop when `i` is 0, `str[l-i]` will hold the null-terminator at the end of the string. Try subtracting 1 from `l` before the `for` loop, but you will need to check for an empty string (length 0) first.

Comment: If `i` is iterated from `i=0` while `i<=l/2`, how many iterations is that? What is the final value of `i` when the loop stops?

Comment: Why count the number of characters that match? As soon as you see a mismatch, you can stop looking at further characters.

Comment: ok sorry got my error

Answer (score 0):

If I add this line into your `for` loop:

```
printf("str[i]=%.2X\tstr[l-i]=%.2X\n", str[i], str[l-i]);
```

With the input `racecar`, which *is* a palindrome, I see the output:

```
str[i]=72       str[l-i]=00
str[i]=61       str[l-i]=72
str[i]=63       str[l-i]=61
str[i]=65       str[l-i]=63
```

You are comparing the null terminator with the actual content of your string, which is not correct. Also, `continue` will end the current iteration of the loop and then update `i` and *keep looping*, which is not what you want once you encounter a failed comparison. You want a `break` there instead. Better yet, have the code in its own function so that you can just return on failure, like this:

```
int palin(char *a, size_t len)
{
    char *p = &a[0];
    char *q = &a[len - 1];
    while(p < q)
    {
        if(*p != *q) return 0;
        p++;
        q--;
    }
    return 1;
}
```